# How to load an Assembly in ASP.NET in runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I want to load an assembly in runtime. I'm using following code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(
    Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SomeTypeFromThisProject).Assembly.Location),
    "MyModule.dll"));
```

This code works fine when running under a Windows Application. But when I'm using it in a WebApplication, it doesn't work.

It seems that ASP.NET keeps each assembly in a separate folder and the assemblies are not placed in same folder.

Sow, how could I load an assembly in a ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Why are you loading the assembly this way and not just adding a refrence to it and loading it normally?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've just simplified the question, in fact the `MyModule.dll` is not fixed and is loaded from an XML file.